# Can I create this crumped paper shader on a curve?

Tags: animation, shaders

[image]
I would like to achieve something similar to the paper that surrounds the perimeter of this package. I would like to use a curve with a bevel, because I would ultimately like to animate the paper being inserted into the box. If it's a mesh with a build modifier, then so be it. I would like to put a fragile item in the box, and then provide paper cushion to the box, in an animation. Let us start with the shader with displacement?

Comment: Interesting challenge.. I'm guessing you mean the crumpled part, not the netted part..

Comment: right. I tried displacement node in the shader but it was not cooperative. Can't use displacement mod on curves.

Comment: You could sculpt a mesh and use a Curve modifier to bend and animate it, or parent it to an armature?

Answer (score 2):

You could sculpt a cylinder to make it look like paper (the hard part in my opinion) and parent your paper to an armature:

[image]